# cordova plugin unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, cordova, plugins

Most of the Cordova plugins have a folder called 'tests', which hosts plugin.xml and tests.js.  Can anyone shed some light on how to run them, and what is required to run?  There seems no relevant documentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There's an official Cordova library for running the unit tests.

From the [Cordova Plugin Test Framework](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-test-framework) on github:

> The `org.apache.cordova.test-framework` plugin does two things:
>
> 1. Defines the interface for cordova plugins to write tests
> 2. Provides a test harness for actually running those tests
>
> Tests run directly
>   inside existing cordova projects, so you can rapidly switch between
>   testing and development. You can also be sure that your test suite is
>   testing the exact versions of plugins and platforms that your app is
>   using.

Visit that page; there's plenty of information there on running existing tests and using the framework for your own plugins.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a plugin called [cordova-paramedic](https://github.com/purplecabbage/cordova-paramedic), based on cordova-test-framework which automates manual steps like modifying `config.xml`:
`cd cordova-plugin-name && npm install cordova-paramedic && node node_modules/cordova-paramedic/main.js --platform android --plugin ./ --verbose`